# parallel streaming and caching of media (audio/video)

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, video-streaming

Im not sure if this is the right title but I'm looking for any leads/resource for streaming and caching of audio/video data.

I have not found anything useful information which is leading me to believe this is not possible.

the ultimate solution is to have something that would upon completion and/or periodically through streaming can cache the media. so I can retrieve at any time.

to be clear, I'm not asking for code or a solution, only resource and the affirmation that; Yes this is possible, or No, this is not possible.

any help would be great on this.
Thanks.